# <meta> for RDFa: "Attribute 'src' not allowed on element 'meta' at this point."

Tags: html, schema.org, rdfa, w3c-validation

I have this code for Schema.org;

```html
<main vocab="http://schema.org"> 
<article  typeof="NewsArticle">

  <h2 property="headline">Wie instaliert Virtual Box in Windows 10</h2>

   <meta property="image" src="Bilder/me.png" >

  <meta property="name" content="Virtual Box" />
  <meta property="mainEntityOfPage" content="http://google.de" />
  <meta property="datePublished" content="2019-03-07" />
  <meta property="dateModified" content="2019-03-17" />
  <span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
    <meta property="name" content="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />
     <span property="logo" typeof="ImageObject">
     <meta property="contentUrl url"  src="/index.php/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" title="VirtualBox"/>
 </span>
 </span>

  <div property="text">Virtual Box ist eine Virtualisierungssoftware, die viele Betriebessysteme emulieren kann. Sie funktioniert mit Linux , Mac und Windows. Sie hat auch veschiedenene Sprachen für ihre Oberfläche, wie beispielsweise Deutsch, Englisch ,... 
  </div>

 <span property="author" typeof="Person" >
  <meta property="name" content="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />
  </span>

</article>
```

With this code , I have no problem with **Google Structured Data Testing Tool**, but when testing it with **validator.w3.org**, it gives me these errors:

[image]

When I tried the recommendation from **validator.w3.org**, I got error in **Google’s SDTT**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `meta` element can’t have a `src` attribute, and if it appears in the `body`, it must have a `content` attribute.

If the value is a URL, you [must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) use the `link` element instead of the `meta` element:

```html
<link property="" href="" />
```

Comment: Thankeeeeeee ! I to do "<meta property="image" content="http://htmlkurss.xyz/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" />" , now come not problem in validator.w3.org and Google  .

Comment: @biotza: It’s still an error, even if the W3C Validator can’t detect it. As I said, you **must** use `link` if the value is a URL.